# thinktecture identityserver - Error The client application is not known or is not authorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver3

Hi I getting a error while using Thinktecture IdentityServer
The error Message 
The client application is not known or is not authorized.
Comes up instead of the login. I can Login to identity server directly however I get the message "You have not given permission to any applications"
I think I may have a problem with the redirect url's but I can't seem to find the bug. Also my MVC Client app works fine until I try to add in the identity server

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks Michael

Here is my Constants.cs file

```
public class Constants
{
    public const string API = "http://localhost:57020/";
    public const string Client = "https://localhost:44306/";
    public const string Mobile = "";

    public const string IdServerUri = "https://identityserver/embedded";

    public const string IdServer = "https://localhost:44302/identity";
    public const string IdServerToken = IdServer + "/connect/token";
    public const string IdServerAuthorize = IdServer + "/connect/authorize";
    public const string IdServerUserInfo = IdServer + "/connect/userinfo";
}
```

Here is my Startup.cs from my WebClient

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "WebClient",
            Authority = Constants.IdServer,
            RedirectUri = Constants.Client,
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = "openid profile",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                MessageReceived = async n =>
                {
                    EndpointAndTokenHelper.DecodeAndWrite(n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken);
                    EndpointAndTokenHelper.DecodeAndWrite(n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);

                    var userInfo = await EndpointAndTokenHelper.CallUserInfoEndpoint(n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Here is the Startup.cs of my Identity Server

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/identity", idServer =>
        {
            idServer.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SiteName = "Embedded Identity Server",
                IssuerUri = Constants.IdServerUri,
                SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),

                Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                    .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get())
                    .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                    .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get())
            });
        });
    }

    X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
    {
        return new X509Certificate2(
            string.Format(@"{0}\bin\myCertificate.com.pfx",
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "******");
    }
}
```

And Finally here is my client.cs

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                Enabled = true,
                ClientId = "WebClient",
                ClientName = "WebClient App",
                Flow = Flows.Hybrid,
                RequireConsent = true,

                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    Constants.Client
                },
            }
        };
```

Comment: Your ClientIds do not match up. I'd start by replacing your ClientId of "mvc" in your UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication with "WebClient"

Comment: @JamieDunstan Good catch, but unfortunately  that was just a typo when I was trying to debug it, I updated the original Thanks

Comment: When I browse to the the Client app. https://localhost:44302/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=WebClient&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44306%2f&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope=openid+profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties               I Can see the redirect happening? to the correct redirect URL set

Comment: Simply turning on logging would immediately solve the problem.

Comment: At a guess I'd say that you're requesting the scope of `"openid profile"`, but your client is not allowed access to any scopes. You should change your client declaration. Either set `AllowAccessToAllScopes` to `true` or add the scopes to the `AllowedScopes` of the client.

Comment: @JamieDunstan Thanks Jamie allowaccesstoallscopes worked.

Comment: @leastprivilege thanks for the tip, I'm definitely turning on logging,  I'm just gettting started with IdentityServer and didn't know about the feature until the past evening. Thanks again for you suggestion.

Comment: There is a reason why access to all scopes is turned off by default.

Comment: @leastprivilege, I only ended up using openid and profile, but using allowaccesstoallscopes=true, pointed me in the right direction. Also on a side note I followed your amazing tutorial on your blog about adding in logging, Thanks a lot for your help